# Convert NSString to NSNumber precision issue

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsnumber

I have a string with about 7 decimal places: `@"-28.1234212"`

and I want to convert it to `NSNumber` without losing any precision. When I do the following, I only end up with 4 decimal places.

```
 NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber* convertedNum = [f numberFromString:@"-28.1234212"];
```

Now convertedNum is `-28.1234` instead of `-28.1234212`.

Is it possible to do this without losing precision?

Comment: Are you sure that the underlying number has actually lost precision (rather than the NSNumber just printing to 4 decimal places)?

Comment: I am both printing and checking the debug.

Comment: Please post the code you used to print it out.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", convertedNum);

Comment: What does this give you? `NSLog(@"%0.16f", convertedNum.doubleValue);`

Comment: Also you don't need to use `NSNumberFormatter`. This should work instead: `NSNumber *convertedNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:@"-28.1234212".doubleValue]`

Comment: So I just decided to access the double value directly from the NSString object and not worry about the conversion. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need a formatter? You can directly convert it into `NSNumber`

```
NSString *douStr = @"-28.1234212";
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:douStr.doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Change number formatter style

```
   [f setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle];
```

use kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle style

```
   NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle];
    NSNumber* convertedNum = [f numberFromString:@"-28.1234212"];

    NSLog(@"%@",convertedNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for precision , you can use NSDecimalNumber.

```
NSDecimalNumber *convertedNUm = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"-28.1234212"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *nowValue =@"-28.1234212";
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle];
NSNumber * nowNum = [f numberFromString:nowValue];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:4]; //set max fraction digit 
NSNumber *nowValueFormatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:nowNum];
NSLog(@"%@",nowNum);
NSLog(@"%@",nowValueFormatted);
```

This might helps you :)